# AAPT: error parsing XML: unbound prefix although namespace is defined

Tags: android

I'm trying to transition my app to the action bar. I'm following [Google's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html). Unfortunately, when trying to build the app, AAPT returns the following error:

```
menu.xml:6: AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

I did some research and found out that this error usually happens when the line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` isn't included in the XML because then AAPT doesn't know how to interpret the `android.xxx` tag. However, as you can see from my code, I've included this line in the first node:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not declared the `app` namespace via `xmlns:app`, but you use it in `app:popupTheme`. IIRC, there is a quick-fix for that in Android Studio. If not, add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root element.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. I was confused by AAPT warning me about line 6 and not line 13 where the `app` reference is but I guess it's warning just about the line of the node...

Comment: @Andreas: Yeah, I suspect that the message is pointing out the location of the problem the element level, not the attribute level.